# Python multiprocessing running faster locally than on cluster (slurm)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, slurm

I have the following code

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

def funct(name):
    if nameisvalid:
        do_some_stuff_and_save_a_file
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

num_proc = 20 #or a call to slurm/mp for number of processors
pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_proc)
results = pool.map_async(makeminofname, [n for n in nameindex])
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I have run this on my desktop with a 6-core processor with `num_proc=mp.cpu_count()` and it works fine and fast, but when I try to run this script in an sbatch script on our processing cluster, with **-N 1 -n 20** (our nodes each have 24 processors), or any number of processors, it runs incredibly slow and only appears to utilize between 10-15 processors. Is there some way to optimize multiprocessing for working with slurm?

Comment: Is your process CPU-bound? From what you write, (''only appears to utilize between 10-15 processors'') it might be IO-bound and if you have an SSD on your desktop and the cluster has a NAS (NFS) and you work on it, then it will be slower on the cluster

Comment: `do_some_stuff_and_save_a_file` writes to a block device?  sounds like that may not be well controlled between the two trials.

Comment: Each call of `funct` read and wrote different files based on `name`, so the different calls won't interfere with eachother beyond I/O locking (which turned out to be the issue).

Answer (score 1):

`funct` checked the disk for a specific file, then loaded a file, then did work, then saved a file. This caused my individual processes to be waiting for input/output operations instead of working. So I loaded all of the initial data before passing it to the pool, and added a `Process` from `multiprocessing` dedicated to saving files from a `Queue` that the pooled processes put their output into, so there is only ever one process trying to save.